# Why does I'm not getting lifecycleScope in Java Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Exactly this below code I want to use in my existing Java class, because write now it is not possible to convert entire class in **Kotlin**:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    viewModel.tasksEvent.collect { event ->
            
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest the best approach. I know `AsyncTask` is deprecated.

Comment: Kotlin make use of property access and java does not that's why . you need to use something like `getViewLifecycleOwner().getLifecycleScope()` .. not sure it it will work `launchWhenStarted` seems to be an extension function i guess and flow also u won't be able to use from Java code  .. better stick to kotlin .. u can convert the class to kotlin from code menu ..

Answer (score 6):

Since `lifecycleScope` it's an extension function you need to call it with a different syntax from java:

```
LifecycleOwnerKt.getLifecycleScope(this)
```

Where `this` is your activity, fragment, etc.

After that you can pass that lifecycleScope to a new kotlin class and return the result with a callback, something like this:

KotlinClass.kt

```
class KotlinClass {
    fun useCoroutineScope(
        scope: LifecycleCoroutineScope,
        callback: (SomeType) -> Unit
    ) {
        scope.launchWhenCreated {
            // Computation code...
            callback(someValue)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken **Kotlin coroutines** are not interoperable with **Java**. To use **Kotlin coroutines** stick to the Kotlin code, don't try to use coroutines in **Java**. Try to convert **Java** file to **Kotlin** file using context menu item **Convert Java File to Kotlin File**. Or move coroutines code to a separate **Kotlin** File.